# Sass if statement

Tags: css, html, sass

I want to achieve something with the if statement in sass.Though I think that the if statement in sass is somehow primitive and restricted in use, but I will be skeptic about that as I'm still a newbie when it comes to sass.

I have a parent div that has 1 image tag by default and the user will be controlling the number of image that should appear as they would be uploading them. so they could upload 3 images, 4, 10 images. 
I want to have an if statement in sass that would apply a default style to the parent div if it only has 1 image in it, and give a condition like if image >1 apply another style to the parent div other than the default one.

I know that my question could be achieved with Javascript, but I'm aiming for sass, it would be good to know that I can achieve such a thing with the if statement of sass.

Comment: There is a great article on sitepoint explaining "quantity queries", it might help you out in this case: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-sass-quantity-queries/

Comment: If I understand, you want to target a div based on the number of its children? CSS doesn't have a parent selector. SASS is just CSS with extra features, so this isn't possible. A quantity query will only affect the children.

This sounds like a good use case for the :has pseudo-class, but it's not available in browsers yet: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has